# One google account, multiple chrome users

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-users

I have a couple of websites, each has a twitter account, disqus account, special bookmarks... managing both of them was annoying, I had to logout, login again with the other account...

I created a new user for siteB, but I haven't logged in with my gmail account as this will take me back to the first problem, not being able to sign in to twitter for example using 2 accounts at the same time.

I still need to sync bookmarks and settings of UserA and UserB on different computers, without mixing A and B together.

How can that be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better, more stable and faster solution is:
Installing a password extension (passwordbox in my case)
each time you want to open a site that you have multiple accounts for, open a new incognito tab, open the site, and click on the account you want to use to login.

Answer (score 0):

This extension for chrome is the closest thing to what I want: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk